# any two Sylow p-subgroups of $GL_2(p)$ generate $SL_2(p)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Is this correct: "any two Sylow p-subgroups of $GL_2(p)$ generate $SL_2(p)$"?

I see this in the book "The Classification of the Finite Simple Groups, Number 5" (p.40).
But I don't know how to prove it.

I know that the order of $GL_2(p)$ is $p(p+1)(p-1)^2$ and the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $GL_2(p)$ is $p+1$.

Comment: The subgroup generated by the two Sylow subgroups must contain all $p+1$ Sylow subgroups by Sylow's theorem, so it is normal in ${\rm SL}_2(p)$. So what do you know about ${\rm SL}_2(p)$?